# how to handle bash * matching when there are no matches?

Tags: bash, globbing

The following bash snippet works great when there are actually `*.txt` files in the directory.

```
for txt in *.txt
do                                               
  echo "loading data from $txt"
done
```

**When there aren't, the literal `*.txt` falls into the loop as $txt (not good).**

*How do I change this code so that when there are no `*.txt` files, the `do ... done` block is skipped?*

Comment: `if [ "*.txt" != '*.txt' ] ; then do loop here ; fi`

Comment: @ott-- +1 for offering an alternative solution

Comment: @ott: `[ "*.txt" != '*.txt' ]` is always false -- both strings are in quotes, so neither gets checked for matches. If you remove the quotes from one it ... has other problems.

Comment: @GordonDavisson +1 for pointing this out: shell scripting seems to be full of surprises...

Comment: @GordonDavisson Indeed, it must be done in 2 steps to work: `files=$(echo *.txt)` and then: `if [ "${files}" != '*.txt' ] ; then`.

Comment: @ott: That'd work (except for the odd case when there's a single file, actually named "*.txt").

Comment: BTW, can be done as single line: `if [ "$(echo *.txt)" != '*.txt') ] ; then`

Answer (score 19):

Put this magic incantation before the `for` statement:

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

([documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html))

Comment: Be aware that this may cause surprise side effects on commands like "ls *.txt"

Answer (score 6):

The nullglob option (@kfmfe04's answer) is best if you are using bash (not a brand-X shell), and don't have to worry about nullglob changing/breaking anything else. Otherwise, you can use this (slightly messier) option:

```
for txt in *.txt
do
  [ -e "$txt" ] || continue
  echo "loading data from $txt"
done
```

This silently skips files that don't exist (mainly "*.txt" if there were no matches, but possibly also files that were deleted between when the `for` generated the list and when the loop got to them...)

Comment: A file might be deleted between `-e` invocation and later processing still...

Comment: @Koterpillar True, but testing `-e` reduces the time window where deletion is a problem.